# Custom service in 'Accounts & Sync'

Tags: android

I have a Twitter widget installed on my Android 2.1 and for now in
'Accounts & sync' app when I press 'Add account' I have ability to add
Twitter account. Moreover screens for adding Twitter account in 'Accounts
& sync' app are made in Twitter design.

Q: How I can put binding to my service in the 'Accounts & sync' as Twitter done?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement SyncAdapter; see [this sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html). I've yet to see a good source of documentation for this, but as far as I can recall, you need to implement an account provider too.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello